# Feed these particular commands to xargs to run in parallel

Tags: google-colaboratory, xargs

Here is the correctly working sequential version:

```
tail -n +2 movieratings.csv | cut -d "|" -f 1 | sort | uniq | wc -l
tail -n +2 movieratings.csv | cut -d "|" -f 2 | sort | uniq | wc -l
tail -n +2 movieratings.csv | cut -d "|" -f 3 | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

and so on for many more f values. The field number is the only thing that changes. Parallelism is required for allowed answers to my question.

I tried lots of things as follows (and even more than shown) if you want to wade through them, but none are working right.  GNU parallel is seemingly not allowed on this host otherwise I would use it and be done with it already. It is a host on google colaboratory. Perhaps there is a way to install GNU parallel on colab and then that answer would also be acceptable to me even if not to the rest of stack overflow. It's my question and I own it.

```
for i in {1..1}; do echo $i; done | xargs -L 30 -I x -n 1 -P 8 cut movieratings.csv -d "|" -f x | sort | uniq | wc -l
for i in {1..2}; do echo $i; done | xargs -I xxx -P 8 cut movieratings.csv -d "|" -f xxx | sort | uniq | wc -l
for i in {1..2}; do echo $i; done | xargs -d $'\n' -I xxx -P 8 cut movieratings.csv -d "|" -f xxx | sort | uniq | wc -l
for i in {1..2}; do echo $i; done | xargs -d $'\n' -n 1 -I xxx -P 8 cut -d "|" -f xxx movieratings.csv | sort | uniq | wc -l
for i in {1..2}; do echo $i; done | xargs -n 1 -I xxx -P 8 cut -d "|" -f xxx movieratings.csv | sort | uniq | wc -l
for i in {1..2}; do echo $i; done | xargs -I xxx -P 8 'cut -d "|" -f xxx movieratings.csv' | sort | uniq | wc -l
for i in {1..2}; do echo $i; done | xargs -I xxx -P 8 cut movieratings.csv -d "|" -f xxx | sort | uniq | wc -l
for i in {1..2}; do echo $i; done | xargs -n 1 -I xxx -P 8 cut movieratings.csv -d "|" -f xxx | sort | uniq | wc -l
for i in {1..2}; do echo $i; done | xargs -I xxx -P 8 "cut movieratings.csv -d '|'" -f xxx | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Here is some sample data on which to run commands. Hope this helps.

```
userid|itemid|rating|rating_year|title|unknown|action|adventure|animation|childrens|comedy|crime|documentary|drama|fantasy|film_noir|horror|musical|mystery|romance|scifi|thriller|war|western|movie_year|movie_age|user_age|gender|job|zipcode
196|242|3.0|1997|Kolya (1996)|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1997|0|49|M|writer|55105
186|302|3.0|1998|L.A. Confidential (1997)|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|1|0|0|1|0|0|1|0|0|1997|1|39|F|executive|00000
22|377|1.0|1997|Heavyweights (1994)|0|0|0|0|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1994|3|25|M|writer|40206
244|51|2.0|1997|Legends of the Fall (1994)|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|1|1|1994|3|28|M|technician|80525
166|346|1.0|1998|Jackie Brown (1997)|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1997|1|47|M|educator|55113
298|474|4.0|1998|Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb (1963)|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|1|0|1963|35|44|M|executive|01581
115|265|2.0|1997|Hunt for Red October, The (1990)|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|1990|7|31|M|engineer|17110
253|465|5.0|1998|Jungle Book, The (1994)|0|0|1|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|1994|4|26|F|librarian|22903
305|451|3.0|1998|Grease (1978)|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|1|0|0|0|0|1978|20|23|M|programmer|94086
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not know colab, but did you read https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/ (Especially `parallel --embed`).

```
tail -n +2 movieratings.csv |
  parallel --tee --pipe 'cut -d "|" -f {} | sort | uniq | wc -l' ::: 1 2 3
```

Comment: I thought I said I know how to do this with your parallel package already. Anyway I got errors when I ran the pip install parallel on colab.  I will record your tip if anything changes though.

Comment: But did you read https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/?

Comment: I have never heard of any system where you can install GNU Parallel by running `pip install parallel`.